# How to view git log in Emacs?

Tags: git, emacs

Emacs shows me conveniently the git log of a single file under git with <kbd>C-x v l</kbd>.  But how can I view the entire history? In the shell I do `git log` in a directory under git. Is there a more emacs-affine way to do this?

Comment: [here](http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-vcs/EmacsGit.html) is the explanation, how to

Answer (score 36, accepted):

<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> - `vc-print-root-log`

I found this easily by asking Emacs to show me the commands with key bindings using the `C-x v` prefix:
<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>C-h</kbd>

You can also easily find this information in the manual. The specific node is:
<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs) VC Change Log`

Personally I use [Magit](http://magit.vc/), though (and recommend that you do likewise).

Comment: Argh, seems that I missed the time to award the bounty. I assumed that this is done automatically with a accepted answer present...

Comment: Oh, that's weird. Maybe give it 24 hours and see what happens? Failing that, you might need to request some support to do anything about it. I can see that the rep has remained missing from your account, but it hasn't been applied here. I know some bounties get applied automatically (or partially; in some situations I know that 50% will be awarded to the "best" answer, even if the user does not allocate it explicitly), but I'm not sure that's the case in this instance.

Comment: Regardless, I'm glad the answer was (presumably) helpful to you @false, and I can tell you that I had a surprising number of up-votes cast while your bounty was present (and undoubtedly on account of it).  I think 10 of the 16 votes happened over these past few days!

Comment: [Here is](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360803/auto-award-mechanism-for-old-questions) what I tried ...

Comment: Thank you @false :)

Answer (score 6):

`C-x v d` lets you open up a VC buffer for a whole directory, where you can select some files (or a directory) and then hit `l` to get the log of these files (or that directory).

Answer (score 4):

I think that [phils's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324105/phils) is already great and it should be awarded the bounty.

An alternative way would be to run `git log` command directly
and have the results displayed in a new buffer using `shell-command` binded to <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>!</kbd> by default.  It would look like that:

[image]

And of course [magit](https://magit.vc) as `phil` already suggested,
by using `magit-status`, <kbd>l</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> or
`magit-log-current`:

[image]

The drawback of `shell-command` is that you can't jump to a commit
under cursor with <kbd>Return</kbd> but you can do that in `magit` and
see this:

[image]